# some of my devices can't connect to my home WIFI network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, modem

All my wireless devices used to be able to connect to my Wifi network.

However my ISP comcast messed up and accidentally disconnected my network. After they restored the service, I found my Samsung Galaxy S4 phone and my XPS 8900 desktop computer can't connect to my WIFI network, all other wireless devices, including 3 iPads, 1 iPhone 6, 1 iMac and 1 Android tablet, Nexus One, were not affected and working as normal.

I have tried to restart my computer and Samsung phone and it didn't work.

My wireless router is Linksys AC1900 and my modem is Arris SB6141.

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: Thanks. you were absolutely right - it turned out the problem was with the router. After I replaced it with a Netgear nighthawk R7000, everything is fine now.

Comment: Glad to hear you have it sorted out. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comcast cannot disconnect your network beyond their modem (unless you gave them access).

Your Linksys AC1900 is controlling the wireless connections, not Comcast's modem. If they had disconnected your Internet access all your devices should still have connected to the wireless network, but would not have been able to access the Internet.

Sounds like you have an issue with your wireless router. Factory reset your Lynksys and go thru the setup again or replace the router.